# How to tell Power BI that it should use a filter inside the calculate formula and use it as filter for other visualizations?

Tags: filter, visualization, powerbi

I am creating a loan process approval report in Power BI. One of the visuals ('funnel') displays the total count of applications, the count of applications approved at the applicant level, the count of applications approved at the product level, and the count of applications that are approved at both levels.

These measures are calculated like this:

```
Approved applicants =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT(ApplicationDecision[applicantEligibility]); 
        ApplicationDecision[applicantEligibility] = 1)
```

I.e., it counts fields in the specific column that are equal to 1 and leaves out the residual 'zero' fields.

What I need is that this funnel visualization works as a filter, i.e. when I click the `'Approved applicants'` panel, all other visualizations will be filtered by the condition `'ApplicationDecision[applicantEligibility] = 1'`.

Is there a way to tell the report that it should take the filter for 'calculate' and make it work as a report-level filter when clicked on?

Thank you very much for any hint, hope I was specific enough!

Edit:

Here is the data example:

```
applicationUniqueId | applicantEligibility | productEligibility | applicationEligibility
       A0001                    1                      1                    1
       A0002                    1                      0                    0
       A0003                    0                      1                    0
       A0004                    1                      1                    1
       A0005                    0                      0                    0
       A0006                    1                      0                    0
```

And for these data, the visual would show me:

```
Applications: 6
Approved applicants: 4
Approved products: 3
Approved applications: 2
```

What I need is that when I click e.g. on row 'Approved applicants', the whole report will filter based on the condition:

```
[applicantEligibility]='1'
```

Comment: Can you please upload simplest case reproducing your data example? Can your case be shown in one table, lets say three columns (all, approved, decisionYES)?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin I added the data example.

Answer (score 0):

The first thought - I would unpivot the data. Then all the funnel types would be in one variable. You can easily slice that variable.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcjQwMDBU0lFC4FgdiKgRVMQAjGGixlARQxRRE6wmmMJ1I6s1QzU3FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"applicationUniqueId " = _t, #"applicantEligibility " = _t, #"productEligibility " = _t, applicationEligibility = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"applicationUniqueId ", type text}, {"applicantEligibility ", Int64.Type}, {"productEligibility ", Int64.Type}, {"applicationEligibility", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"applicationUniqueId "}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "variable"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```